# Adding coins in unity after successful iOS In-App purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

I am using SDKbox for Unity to add in app purchases to my app. The products (consumable virtual currency) are added in iTunes and in unity, and when compiled in Xcode, they will execute in sandbox successfully.

But I am having problems assigning the purchased coins to the dataGame file. When I use the code below (updated from SDKbox code) to assign the coins (Insulinium in this game) the app will compile in Xcode, successfully run one in-app purchase, and then freeze without giving the user the purchased coins.

```
public void onInitialized(bool status)
    {
        Debug.Log("PurchaseHandler.onInitialized " + status);
    }

    public void onSuccess(Product product)
    {
        Debug.Log("PurchaseHandler.onSuccess: " + product.name);
        if (product.name == "Insulinium150")
        { 
            dataGame.coin += 150;
        }
            if (product.name == "Insulinium450")
        { 
            dataGame.coin += 450;
        }
            if (product.name == "Insulinium1500")
        {
            dataGame.coin += 1500;
        }
        uiManager.SetCoin ();
    }
```

I've looked everywhere and the lack of answer makes me think I am missing something pretty easy. I understand the basics of C# and unity coding, but I could have easily overlooked something. Anyone have any thoughts?

What is the best way to add virtual currency to your game file after a successful in-app purchase on iOS?

Comment: What's happening inside the uiManager.SetCoin() method? I can see no syntax error or similar. Checked that the product names is right?

Comment: All we can tell you is that the error probably occurs anywhere but here. I understand that you're using a third-party add-on for managing coins? If that's the case, you should raise this issue with whatever party made this functionality.

Comment: thanks, moved this request to developer's forums.